# Create a php file with the value of echo values

Tags: php, file, echo, render

I have a piece of code like this:

```
$classVoHeader = 'class C'.toCamelCase($tableName,true).'Vo{';
$classVoFooter = '}';
$str ='public $table_map = array(';
$propertyStr = '';
foreach($columnInfos as $column){
$str.=$br.'\''.$column['Field'].'\' => \''.toCamelCase($column['Field']).'\',';
    $propertyStr.=$br.'public $'.toCamelCase($column['Field']).';';
}
$str.=$br.');';
echo $classVoHeader.$br;
echo $str;
echo $propertyStr.$br;
echo $classVoFooter;
```

And I want to create a php file that have content is all of what it echoed.
Is it impossible?

Comment: you can have a text file where you can dump all the text this code echoed

Comment: what did you meant? 
@ViswanathPolaki can you tell me more details :D Thanks

Comment: You should have a read of [How to write to a text file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) in the PHP manual.

Comment: @cept0 i think this question is perfectly normal

Comment: create a text file in server and open the file in write mode and write the variables values in the file and close it.

Comment: This question addresses two problems: 1) How to get all echoed output and 2) How to write it to a file. Perfectly normal question, i wonder why the downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php to save what is being printed into a buffer, then use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php to save this string to a file

Answer (score 1):

Strange question but, here you go:

```
 $Result = '<?php ' . $classVoHeader.$br . $str . $propertyStr.$br . $classVoFooter . ' ?>';

 $file = fopen("result.php","w");
 echo fwrite($file,$Result);
 fclose($file);
```

Comment: echo $classDaoHeader;
  echo 'private $conn;'.$br;
  echo 'public function __construct($conn) {'.$br;
Thanks for you reply :D 
Actually I have many echos with some code syntax in that just like these above and I want to write all echoed value to the new file.
It just like a new php file with classes and functions :D

Answer (score 1):

i dont know what your code is and it doesnt matter. With my answer you will have all the output that is produced between `ob_start();` and `ob_get_clean();` saved to the variable `$the_output_of_code`. Then just write this to a file.

```
<?php
    ob_start();

    // your code begins here

    // [your piece of code here whatever]

    $classVoHeader = 'class C'.toCamelCase($tableName,true).'Vo{';
    $classVoFooter = '}';
    $str ='public $table_map = array(';
    $propertyStr = '';
    foreach($columnInfos as $column){
        $str.=$br.'\''.$column['Field'].'\' => \''.toCamelCase($column['Field']).'\',';
        $propertyStr.=$br.'public $'.toCamelCase($column['Field']).';';
     }
     $str.=$br.');';
     echo $classVoHeader.$br;
     echo $str;
     echo $propertyStr.$br;
     echo $classVoFooter;

    // your code ends here

    $the_output_of_code = ob_get_clean();

    $file = fopen("the_output.php","w");
    fwrite($file,$the_output_of_code);
    fclose($file);

?>
```

Comment: thanks, I will try.
Actually I have many echos after them, just want to echo all the value to a new file.